# How to Use Column to Background Fill in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to use background fill for column in on my chart. I couldn't put background column over other main used column.

**My chart display :**

[image]

**Scripts:**

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Günlük Endüktif - Kapasitif Ceza Limiti Değerleri'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: ''
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: result.DateList
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Oran (%)'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
                footerFormat: '</table>',
                shared: true,
                useHTML: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    pointPadding: 0.2,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    borderRadius: 20,
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    animation: true,
                    grouping: 'false'
                },
                line: {
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                },
                series: {
                    grouping: 'false',
                    stacking : 'normal'
                }

            },
            series:
             [
             //{
             //   name: result.Name,
             //   data: dynamic_data1,
             //   type: 'column'
             //},
              {
                 name: 'null',
                 data: [30, 30, 30, 30, 30],
                 borderWidth: 0,
                 stack: 1,
                 animation: false,
                 color: "gray"
             },
             series, {
                name: 'Ceza Limiti',
                type: 'line',
                data: result.Average,
                marker: {
                    lineWidth: 2,
                    lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
                    fillColor: 'white'
                }
            }]
        });
```

**I need a result as :**

[image]

So, where is my mistake in script or what is missing?

Comment: The sun icon should be inside column or column should have a pattern with sun?How it should look like, in general ?

Comment: No Sebastian, i dont need sun icon. Only i need to get background fill column on all series

Comment: Please replicate your exampel as live demo (including data etc) and descirbe which scenario you need (first image or last), because your quesiton is unclear.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your help, i have solved my problem.